# How to fit text inside a shape using iDraw

Tags: svg, path, idraw

I'm trying to design a logo, and would like to fit the name of the product inside a shape. In this case, the shape is a closed path in the shape of a smile. Any ideas how I might achieve that?

Basically, the top of the letters should follow the path along top of the smile, and the bottom of the letters should follow the path along the bottom of the smile - with the size, shape, shear (etc.) of the letters adjusted accordingly.

I've tried both manually manipulating the outlines of text (once converted to an outline) to try and fit the shape, and using the fit to path. Neither of these really worked, and I was hoping that there was a better 'automated' solution that would produce better results than me trying to do it by hand.

I'm currently using iDraw on the Mac to do the design (so SVG for those unfamiliar with it).

Comment: Not sure if there are many here with experience with iDraw, so I cannot really be concrete since I do not have any images to go on. But it sounds to me that this is a manual job; to get a decent result you need to do it "by hand".

Comment: Hi James, thanks for adding new info. I edited your comment into your question and removed it from here so it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You need the kind of deformations that iDraw doesn't have the most powerful of, they're called Distortions.

You might have to convert the text to independent vector lines before distorting to get the best results.

It's possible. Just a bit of fiddling with those distortion tools and you should find the ones that do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late.

1. select the text and path or shape you want to place the text on.
2. From the modify menu from the menu bar at the top and select place text on path

Comment: Hello and welcome, I have editted your answer slightly if you feel that this somehow mangled your original meaningplease revert.